# Floor function and Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm doing a proof and I'm just down to this and I'll be done.

If $p$ is prime, is $2 \lfloor \frac{p}{2} \rfloor +1 =p$ ? I think it holds, just don't know how to prove it.

I'm searching for properties of floor functions but I can't find one. Thanks.

Comment: It does not hold for $p=2$.

Comment: But it does hold if $p \neq 2$. Use the fact that all such primes are odd. (why?)

Comment: That is true for all odd numbers. So this holds for all primes expect $2$.

Comment: Thank you guy! I missed it. It holds for all primes $p$ except when $p=2$.